# Sequence limit with complex numbers, where $ u_n=\Re(({\frac{1+i\sqrt{7}}{2}})^n) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, complex-numbers

How do you prove :

$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$  if $ u_n=\Re(({\frac{1+i\sqrt{7}}{2}})^n) $  where  $\Re$  mean the real part of a complex number, that $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\left | u_n \right |=+\infty$$

$\left | u_n \right |$ is the modulus of $u_n$